# Best way to Change width of drop down in semantic UI

Tags: drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

What is the best way to Change width of drop down in semantic UI, so that it will be responsive.

Comment: Please provide some code of your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="city" class="colomn ui search selection dropdown" style="min-width: 121px; white-space: nowrap;  max-width: 251px;">
                <input type="hidden" name="country">
                <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                <div class="default text">Select City</div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="item" data-value="Ahmedabad">Ahmedabad</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="Bangalore">Bangalore</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="Chennai">Chennai</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="Delhi">Delhi</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="Kolkata">Kolkata</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="Mumbai">Mumbai</div>
                </div>
            </div>

<style>
.ui.dropdown>.text {
        display: block !important;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```